# Choose three emails at random from an indefinite group of emails

Tags: php, email, random

it's the first time I'm writing here, sorry for any mistakes.
I'm not a programmer, I usually try to study the advice you give on this site and find a way to apply it to my needs but this time I just can't find a solution.
I use an email plugin for wordpress that allows me to put a tag like this [emails-group] in the "Bcc" field, this tag can contain one or more email addresses separated by commas.
with the code I wrote below (I don't know if it's written in the best way) I can send an email to two random email addresses when the email addresses are three. (this code works in my tests)

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced',
  function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
    if ( 'emails-group' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
    foreach($submitted as $value){
        $expl = explode(",", $value);
        $list = array("$expl[0]","$expl[1]","$expl[2]");
        $rand_keys = array_rand($list, 2);
        $first = $list[$rand_keys[0]];
        $second = $list[$rand_keys[1]];
         $result = array("$first","$second");
    $replaced = implode(",",$result);
    }
    }
    return $replaced;
  },
   10, 4
);
```

what I would need is a new code for:

if the email addresses are one or two or three then send everyone the email, but if the email addresses are more than three choose only three email addresses at random and send them the email.

I thank anyone who can put me on the right way to find the solution.
Greetings,
Raffaele.

Comment: See the [docs for array_rand, second parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):  "num, Specifies how many entries should be picked."   So, choosing 3 random values from the list of email addresses should not be a problem.

Comment: thanks for you answer, yes i know i can write 
$rand_keys = array_rand($list, 3); and then  
$first = $list[$rand_keys[0]];
$second = $list[$rand_keys[1]];
$third= $list[$rand_keys[2]];
but what i can write into variable $list?

Comment: i think my problem is i don't know how to make  $list = array( of all elements that could derive from $expl)

Comment: In those docs (see earlier comment) is (under Returned values): "... Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$expl` seems to have a list of all the email addresses.

Try:

```
$list = $expl;
$rand_keys = array_rand($list, 3);
$first = $list[$rand_keys[0]];
$second = $list[$rand_keys[1]];
$third = $list[$rand_keys[1]];
```

Comment: thank you very much, my error was $list=array($expl), when i tried to use only $expl.
this because i was sure that i have need to write "array"  because i used array when i wrote  array("$expl[0]","$expl[1]","$expl[2]");
your solution is perfect, I have made many attempts and it works.
The code below only works if the email addresses are more than three, this too I tried many times, do you think it is written correctly?

Answer (score 0):

my final code that works for me is:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced',
      function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
        if ( 'emails-group' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
        foreach($submitted as $value){
            $expl = explode(",", $value);
            if (count($expl) >= 3){
            $list = $expl;
            $rand_keys = array_rand($list, 3);
            $first = $list[$rand_keys[0]];
            $second = $list[$rand_keys[1]];
            $third = $list[$rand_keys[2]];
             $result = array("$first","$second","$third");
        $replaced = implode(",",$result);
        } else {
                $replaced = $value;
            }
            }
        }
        return $replaced;
      },
       10, 4
    );
```

thank you very much to Luuk for his availability.
You made my Sunday better